# Macbook Pro 16" shuts down after a while in sleep mode

Tags: catalina, sleep-wake, shutdown

I have a 2020 16-inch Macbook Pro running macOS 10.15.5. Recently, it has started shutting down after it's been in sleep mode for a while. This happens quite often and is annoying because I have to rely on autosave mode for various programs. When I start it back up, it says my computer shut down due to a problem and offers to report it to Apple. However, when I look at the shutdown causes, I get number 5 (correct shutdown):

```
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL  
2020-06-15 09:21:44.476694+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-15 13:14:48.313305+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-15 17:48:48.208832+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-15 21:40:22.955534+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-16 09:36:04.794137+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-16 14:14:14.458370+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-16 18:48:45.251752+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-17 09:23:33.773847+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2020-06-17 13:15:24.859400+0200 0xd5       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Log      - Default:          9, Info:                0, Debug:             0, Error:          0, Fault:          0
Activity - Create:           0, Transition:          0, Actions:           0
```

This is what I get for `pmset -g`:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                0
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

And this is [what the report to Apple contains](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/15de9825ee294a6afd42669a46f5858b) (please let me know if I should delete this in case it contains sensitive information).

I have reset the SMC and NVRAM to no avail.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109556/discussion-on-question-by-flobin-macbook-pro-16-shuts-down-after-a-while-in-sle).